# Run a php-scripts from a echo $page['content']

Tags: php, function

I need to run a PHP scripts from ECHO.
Normally, the output that comes from the database is a text, but sometimes there is also the php code within.
['content'] is defined as LONGBLOB in my database.
How do I get it to work together?

```
function data_page ($dbc, $pageid){

    $q = "SELECT * FROM page WHERE id = $pageid";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r); 

    return $data;
}

$page=data_page($dbc,$pageid);

<?php echo $page['content'];?>
```

`content` can contain for example this code `<?php echo date('Y');?>`

Comment: Why would you store `<?php echo date('Y');?>` in the database? Why not just call that where you need to in a php file? Or use SQL to get the date.

Comment: Why do you have `echo $page` inside PHP brackets? `<?php ?>` You're already in PHP mode.  If I understand the problem, you want to just echo the result when it's text, but what do you want to do with the result when it's PHP code?

Comment: `eval('?>'.$page['content']);`

Comment: [Content] is part of a database, which contains more information. Sometimes it's just text, other times it is a database Requests to be run.
I wrote that it might be an example.
I should be able to execute the code that is located in the [content].

Answer (score 0):

I knew PHP would let this happen cause why not. I am only showing this because yes it can be done. You should think about this though. You can easily get the information from SQL. I am not sure what else you have in the DB though and this should work in most cases.

You will need to clean the string up. You cannot have another `<?php ?>` block inside an existing one. So the string in the DB should be `echo date('Y');`

Then in your code you can call this:

```
<?php
function data_page ($dbc, $pageid){

    $q = "SELECT * FROM page WHERE id = $pageid";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r); 

    return $data;
}

$page=data_page($dbc,$pageid);

eval($page['content']);

?>
```